# MVC how to return VIEW for more than one grid on home page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have multiple grids I want to put on the home page only but when I return more than one in View, it shows me an error.

It said I can try to throw new exception but still an error. How do I get it to show more than one grid?? The grids are created in lists in the model.

```
@using GridMvc.Html;
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Activities>
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Cities>

@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Homestyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1 align="center" id="homewords">Home</h1><br/><br/><br/>
    <p id="mainp" align="center">
        Welcome to What2Do, we are a website to help you find things to do around town as a local or a tourist. We are a brand new website
        and we are still looking for more places and cities in the future. If you have any good ideas or know good places, please see the about
        page to email this information! Hope you enjoy! :)
    </p>
     <br /><br />
    <div id="city">
        <p id="choosecity">City: </p>
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(cols =>
    {
       cols.Add(c => c.stpete).Titled("St. Petersburg");
       cols.Add(c => c.tampa).Titled("Tampa");
       cols.Add(c => c.orlando).Titled("Orlando");
   });

</div>       
<div id="act" align="center">
        <p  id="activity">Activity: </p>
        <select id="ddlactivity" name="activity" size="4">
            <option value="1">Theme Parks</option>
            <option value="2">Outdoor Activities</option>
            <option value="3">Beach Activities</option>
            <option value="4">Bars and Music</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>

    <div id="results" width="500px">

        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns=>
   {
       columns.Add(c => c.activity).Titled("Activity");
       columns.Add(c => c.location).Titled("Location");
       columns.Add(c => c.cost).Titled("Cost");
       columns.Add(c => c.hours).Titled("Hours");

   }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)

    </div>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Website.Models;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Default
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var citymodel = new Cities();
            List<Cities> citygrid = citymodel.city();
            var model = new Activities();
            List<Activities> actgrid = model.Acts();

            return View(actgrid, citygrid);

        }
```

Comment: Use a view model that contains properties for each of your collections

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this but in and of itself, a View can only have a single model feeding into it.

You could create a ViewModel class containing both models or you could refactor your one View into one with several PartialViews in it, each having a model feeding into it.

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Activities>
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Cities>
```

How would the view know which one to map to

```
@Html.Grid(Model)?
```

A view can only have a single model, either combine these Enumerables into a single model or break the views down into partials that can have their own views.

You would have your primary view with no grids in it and then two partials each wrapping a grid with the connected controllers actions for each partial getting and attaching the correct model for that specific grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting two type of model list in your view it will nor work:

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Activities>
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Cities>
```

To use multiple model list in view use Touple OR add main model and then assign list of model as property in that model

**Touple:**

```
model Tuple<IEnumerable<Website.Models.Activities>,IEnumerable<Website.Models.Cities>>;
```

## Example:

**Class:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
}

public class UserEducation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int PassingYear { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        User objUser = new User();
        objUser.Id = i;
        objUser.Name = "Name" + i.ToString();
        userList.Add(objUser);
    }

    List<UserEducation> userEducationList = new List<UserEducation>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        UserEducation objUserEducation = new UserEducation();
        objUserEducation.Id = i;
        objUserEducation.Education = "Education" + i.ToString();
        objUserEducation.PassingYear = 2015+i;
        userEducationList.Add(objUserEducation);
    }

    return View(new Tuple<List<User>, List<UserEducation>>(userList, userEducationList));
}
```

View:

```
@model Tuple<List<TestMVCApp.Models.User>, List<TestMVCApp.Models.UserEducation>>
@{
     Layout = null;
 }

 <style>
    tr th,tr td{
       padding:10px;
    }
  </style>
  <body style="margin-left:20px">
   <div style="float:left;clear:both;font-weight:bold;color:red;font-size:20px;">
    Users:
</div>
<div style="float:left;clear:both">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>


</div>
<div style="float:left;clear:both;font-weight:bold;color:red;font-size:20px;">
    User Education:
</div>
<div style="float:left;clear:both">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Education
            </th>
            <th>
                PassingYear
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Item2)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Education</td>
                <td>@item.PassingYear</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]